# Is there a way to have a mandatory checklist before changing the state of a user story?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

In a similar way to Dynamics having fields that must be completed before progressing an opportunity, is there a way to have mandatory fields filled out before being able to change the state to “done” for instance?

Comment: On-prem, or cloud?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, you could add a custom field in the inheritance process, and then add a [rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) to the user story. (Inheritance process)

[image: ForState in user stroy]

[image]